# Difference between IWorkbenchWindow and IWorbenchPage in Eclipse SDK

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I still don't get what the difference is between the two. The eclipse docs just say that a window can have many pages, but when does that happen? Under what circumstances is the number of pages more than one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have multiple pages in a window only if you are running Eclipse 2.0 or earlier. The API is there only to maintain binary backward compatibility with the older releases. Eclipse 3.x doesn't have multiple pages per workbench window.